# Градиент на части объекта в illustrator cc2018

Tags: вектор, градиент, adobe, illustrator

У меня есть круг с градиентом, мне нужно разрезать его напополам так, чтобы центр градиента не смещался. При попытке обрезать ножом, ножницами, или перекрыть прямоугольником и через обработку контуров обрезать лишнее всегда один результат - центр  градиента смещается

[image: круг с градиентом]

круг с градиентом

[image: круг разрезанный ножом]

круг разрезанный ножом

[image: после наложения поверх другой фигуры и обработки контуров]

после наложения поверх круга белого прямоугольника и обработки контуров

[image: такой результат в итоге нужно получить]

такой полукруг с таким градиентом в итоге нужно получить

Answer (score 0):

Сначала создаёте новую фигуру (разрезаете круг), а потом создаёте градиент (тянете инструментом Gradient Tool (G) от центра изначального круга).